# SQL Select non standard date older then X

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to select a date field which is not in a standard format and only select dates that are older than X number of days. Done some searching and found some examples here but I can't seem to get mine to work.

My date format is like this: Wed Dec  3 09:00:46 2014
which is located in a column: rundate (TEXT)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE rundate < DATEADD((day, -5, GETDATE()), '%a %b %e %T %Y')
```

I get error like: FUNCTION myDB.DATEADD does not exist

Any idea how I can get this to work? My end goal is to delete old records but for now selecting them would be great! Hope you can help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`date_add`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) (note the underscore).
Moreover, instead of comparing text representations of dates (i.e., converting both to strings), you should be converting the string to a date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(rundate, '%a %b %e %T %Y') < 
       DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
```

Also, if you want to subtract dates, then [`date_sub`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) may be a tad more intuitive:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(rundate, '%a %b %e %T %Y') < 
       DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both queries and I get the same error: myTable.GETDATE does not exist

Comment: I don't know why I had it in my head that this was MS-SQL. In MySQL, the current date is `curdate()`, not `getdate()` - see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Updated script is working. Just wanted to confirm both examples above are doing roughly the same thing or am I missing something? They both seem to be selecting all records after the most current 5 days.

Comment: @Plexter yup, both examples do exactly the same. I just wanted to note that using `date_sub` for subtraction is more intuitive than using `date_add` with a negative value.